# Checking if a key exists in a Snowflake variant

Tags: key, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, exists

Is there a function to check if a key exists in a Snowflake variant field?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [IS_NULL_VALUE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/is_null_value) to see if the key exists. If the key does not exist, the result will be NULL. If the key exists, the result will be TRUE if the value is JSON null or FALSE if there's a non-null JSON value:

```
select  parse_json('{hello: NULL, world: 123}') as V,
        V:hello, 
        V:world,
        IS_NULL_VALUE(v:hello),
        IS_NULL_VALUE(v:world),
        IS_NULL_VALUE(v:goodbye),
        IFF(IS_NULL_VALUE(v:non_existing_key) is null, 'Key does not exist', 'Key exists'),
        IFF(IS_NULL_VALUE(v:hello) is null, 'Key does not exist', 'Key exists'),
        IFF(IS_NULL_VALUE(v:world) is null, 'Key does not exist', 'Key exists')
;
```

Also, the [STRIP_NULL_VALUE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/strip_null_value) function can be used to verify is field json null or absent

```
select  parse_json('{hello: NULL, world: 123}') as V,
    STRIP_NULL_VALUE(v:non_existing_key),
    STRIP_NULL_VALUE(v:hello),
    STRIP_NULL_VALUE(v:world);
```

Comment: This assumes a flat variant structure.

Comment: Yes... Not sure of the use case precisely. The IS_NULL_VALUE will determine if a key is present where expected, but not tell you if it's anywhere in the JSON the way your recursive flatten does. That's a great approach I'll have to test; thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a way to find an attribute within a nested JSON structure that might be complex, you could run something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM x
,LATERAL FLATTEN(parse_json(x.var), recursive => True) x2
WHERE x2.key = 'test';
```

This flattens the whole structure out and gives you every key available in the JSON at any level.  If the count is 0, then it doesn't exist.  If run a straight select, rather than a COUNT(*) it'll show you the value, as well, and you can determine where in the nesting the attribute exists.

Comment: Thanks, that is clever

Comment: What is the purpose of `x2`?

Comment: x2 is just the alias for the LATERAL FLATTEN results.  Technically, I should have added that to the key to read `WHERE x2.key = 'test'`.  I will edit.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Mike

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a combination of OBJECT_KEYS function, which outputs an array of only the existing keys in the Variant & ARRAY_CONTAINS function to return the Boolean value. See below.

```
SELECT ARRAY_CONTAINS('<key_to_search_for>'::VARIANT, OBJECT_KEYS(<variant_column>))
FROM <table_name>;
```